# Storing profile pic of users in database: Small sized images, hence in database?

Tags: database, image, storage, cassandra, theory

How to store and retrieve the profile pic image of the users on the server ? In the database or using File System? I heard that storing in DB is preferable for small images. If size would be small around from 60*60 px to 80*80 px then retreivals would be faster as compared to file system!?

*[My database is Cassandra.]*

Answer (score 3):

You can store a picture in Cassandra in raw bytes. if you are using Java, you can refer the following link -
https://github.com/rantav/hector/tree/master/core/src/main/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/io

Also the following discussions might help -
http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/Storing-photos-images-docs-etc-td6078278.html

Comment: hector is really cool!!! Do you know any other great Cassandra projects on Github? Thanks a million!!!